# Fedora 38 x86-64 Live environment doesn't boot past Grub

Tags: linux, fedora, grub

**The issue:** I tried another distro for Sh*ts and giggles. Downloaded the Fedora ISO again and passed the checksums. However, it doesn't boot passed Grub. I was on Fedora 38 on this laptop before.

**What I have tried:** To make sure I wasn't crazy, I was able to boot with it in VirtualBox and Gnome Boxes without issue. I have used Fedoras image writer, Open Susa, and the dd command. None of them work, but I can get every other distro to boot, Arch, Manjaro, and Pop OS. I don't have and Nvidia card, Intel integrated graphics.

I posted on the Fedora forum and I only got one comment about the bug I posted below. https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/16swoiv/fedora_38_x8664_live_environment_doesnt_boot_past/?sort=new

**helpful info:**

Currently on Arco Linux (Arch base)

I am aware of this https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2113005
but, that shouldn't matter. I have had this same distro installed a couple of weeks ago.

hwinfo --short

cpu:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 2000 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 2000 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 1994 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 2000 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 2000 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 2000 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 400 MHz

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz, 1575 MHz

keyboard:

/dev/input/event4 Microsoft Surface 045E:09AE Keyboard

mouse:

/dev/input/mice Microsoft Surface 045E:09AF Mouse

/dev/input/mice Microsoft Surface 045E:09AF Touchpad

monitor:

LQ135P1JX51

graphics card:

Intel Iris Plus Graphics G7

sound:

Intel Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller

storage:

SK hynix BC501 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB

network:

wlp0s20f3 Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201

network interface:

wlp0s20f3 Ethernet network interface

lo Loopback network interface

disk:

/dev/nvme0n1 SK hynix BC501 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB

partition:

/dev/nvme0n1p1 Partition

/dev/nvme0n1p2 Partition

/dev/nvme0n1p3 Partition

usb controller:

Intel Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller

Intel Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller

bios:

BIOS

bridge:

Intel Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller

Intel Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers

Intel Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9

hub:

Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

memory:

Main Memory

bluetooth:

Intel Bluetooth Device

unknown:

FPU

DMA controller

PIC

Keyboard controller

Intel Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1

Intel Communication controller

Intel Signal processing controller

Intel Ice Lake-LP Management Engine

Intel Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller

Intel Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2c Controller #4

Intel Ice Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0

Intel Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0

Intel Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller

Microsoft Surface Camera Front